# Busca Array com variavel case-insensitive javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

Preciso fazer uma busca em um array com valores do tipo:

```
equipamentos = [{marca: 'Nomedamarca1', modelo: 'Modelo1'},
                {marca: 'Nomedamarca2', modelo: 'Modelo2'},
                {marca: 'AlgumNomeComCase', modelo: 'Modelo3'},
                {marca: 'OutroNomeComCase', modelo: 'Modelo4'}]
```

porem no meu input, quero aceitar valores em low-case, exemplo:

Quando o usuário digitar "nome", a busca deve retornar: "[Nomedamarca1, Nomedamarca2,AlgumNomeComCase,OutroNomeComCase]"

Quando o usuário digitar "algumnome", a busca deve retornar: "[AlgumNomeComCase]"

Estou usando a função filter e match, porém ela não é case-insensitive.

```
ShowDShowDropModelrep(value) {

const marca = this.modelsfull.filter( obj => obj[ 'marca' ].match( value ) );
const modelo = this.modelsfull.filter( obj => obj[ 'modelo' ].match( value ) );
Object.keys(marca).forEach(function(key) { modelo[key] = marca[key]; });
this.marcamodelo = modelo; }
```

Lendo a documentação da função match ([doc do mozila](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)) tentei sem sucesso o seguinte:

```
value = '/' + value + '/gi';
```

Uma das possíveis soluções seria aplicar .toLowerCase() em todas as posições do array, porém necessito manter os dados originais com as case originais.

Comment: Qual é o problema em usar `toLowerCase()`? Ele só vai alterar o valor original se você atribuí-lo!

Comment: A questão que eu preciso dessa função agindo no array, não na variável passando como parametro.. 
Mas no caso você diz: obj.toLowerCase() => obj[ 'marca' ].match( value ) ?

Comment: Funcionou desta forma:
const modelo = this.modelsfull.filter( obj => obj[ 'modelo'].toLowerCase().match( value ) );
Obrigado @WallaceMaxters.

Comment: posta a solução como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em cima do comentário do wallace, consegui resolver meu problema desta forma:

```
ShowDShowDropModelrep(value) {
   const marca = this.modelsfull.filter( obj => obj[ 'marca' ].toLowerCase().match( value ) );
   const modelo = this.modelsfull.filter( obj => obj[ 'modelo' ].toLowerCase().match( value ) );
   Object.keys(marca).forEach(function(key) { modelo[key] = marca[key]; });
   this.marcamodelo = modelo;}
```